# google map API v3 only part of the map appear and other parts appear on resizing window or draging map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add custom map to my website and its my first time to use Google maps API V3

The problem is that only part of the map appears inside the map div, and all the remaining parts of the map stay unloaded unless i re-size my browser or drag the visible part of the map it start to load normally .

Here is the HTML code

```
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:40%; height:1000px"></div>
```

And Here is the jquery code

```
function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
            var settings = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 

            });
```

you can also check contact us on the following test link [Here is the link](http://thesevenlayers.net/amak/html/)

Comment: This is not enough code to be able to help, what is #map_canvas, is it initially hidden?

Comment: Please check my edit also please check the link at the end of my question

Answer (score 1):

As the map is not visible initially, you must trigger the resize-event of the map (or the window ) when the map will be shown.
This will force the API  to load the missing tiles.

The callback of `$.animate()` at the end of `openSection()` should be a good place for this.